# Easiest way to alert a form's data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Simple question I can't seem to get right. I have a form `#formOne`, I need to alert it's data. Something isn't working,

```
$("#formOne").submit(function(){
  alert("you are submitting" + data);
)};
```

If not `data` what do you use after `+`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to see what the POST string looks like:

```
$("#formOne").submit(function(){
  alert("you are submitting" + $(this).serialize());
});
```

Make sure that `#formOne` is the form itself, so that `this` refers to the `<form>` element when serializing.  For debugging you may always want to try this instead (using Firebug or Chrome):

```
$("#formOne").submit(function(){
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
});
```

This will print out as an array of objects with a `name` and a `value` property, a bit easier to read, at least to me.

Comment: @Nick - as usual thanks! It was a curiosity, as im sure ill have to show it at some point. thx man!

Comment: and if it's not? say the submit function is bound to a button, maybe #sbtBtn? :) I tried plugging in $("#formOne") in place of $(this) - no joy

Comment: @Dirty - The `submit` event is on the `<form>`, no matter where you're firing it from, you should use that as your attachment point, even if something else *triggers* it, your submit handler should be on the `<form>` itself.

Comment: @Nick - awesome. firebug, much better. Thanks man. thats slick.